# Форма удаляется сама после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть сайт, внизу есть [форма](http://torgovaya-sibir.ru/). Нажимаю на кнопку "**отправить**", все содержимое в теге form удаляется со страницы.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("form").submit(function (e) {
        sendForm(this); // !!! передавайте элемент формы в функцию sendForm
        return false;
      });
    });
    
    function sendForm(form) {
      var formNm = $(form);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          formNm.html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
          formNm.html(error);
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-block-content-object">
                <div class="form-block-content-object-title">Оставить заявку</div>
                <div class="form-block-content-object-input-lb">Ваше имя</div>
                <input style="padding=left:10px" name="user_name" type="text" class="form-block-content-object-input">
                <div class="form-block-content-object-input-lb">Ваш телефон</div>
                <input  style="padding=left:10px" name="user_phone" type="number" class="form-block-content-object-input">
                <button   type="submit" class="form-block-content-object-button">Отправить</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Ваш код в студию?

Comment: Код чего именно?Формы?

Comment: Ну как минимум `html` и `js`

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Так вы ж стриаете её после ответа сервера)

Comment: Какой строчкой именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при ответе или ошибки в тег `form` выводился ответ сервера:

```
success: function (data) {
   formNm.html(data);
},
error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
   formNm.html(error);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
            sendForm(this); // !!! передавайте элемент формы в функцию sendForm
            return false;
          });
        });
        
function sendForm(form) {
    let formNm = $(form)
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'mail.php',
      data: formNm.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
          $(formNm).after(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
          $(formNm).after(error);
      }
  });
}
```

Я вставил метод `after`, теперь ответ будет выводиться после тега `form`.

Answer (score -1):

return false перенесите в ajax запрос.